# Pandas. Selection by label. One-row output

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to select every entry in a pandas DataFrame D, correspoding to some certain userid, filling missing etime values with zeros as follows:

```
user_entries = D.loc[userid]
user_entries.index = user_entries.etime
user_entries = user_entries.reindex(range(distinct_time_entries_num))
user_entries = user_entries.fillna(0)
```

The problem is, for some ids, there exists exactly one entry, and thus .loc() method is returning a Series object with an unexpected index:

```
(Pdb) user_entries.index = user_entries.etime
*** TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 388 was passed
(Pdb) user_entries
etime        388
requested      1
rejected       0
Name: 351, dtype: int64
(Pdb) user_entries.index
Index([u'etime', u'requested', u'rejected'], dtype='object')
```

which is painful to handle. I'd seiously prefer a DataFrame object with one row. Is there any way around it? Thanks.

UPD: A have to apologize for unintengible formulation, this is my first post here. I'll try again.
So the deal is: there is a dataframe, indexed by userid. Every userid can possibly have up to some number N corresponding dataframe rows (columns are: 'etime','requested','rejected') for which 'etime' is basically the key. For some 'userid', there exist all of the N corresponding entries, but for the most of them, there are missing entries for some 'etime'. 
My intensions are: for every 'userid' construct an explicit DataFrame object, containing all N entries indexed by 'etime', filled with zeros for the missing entries. That's why I'm changing index to 'etime' and then reindexing selected row subset with the full 'etime' range.
The problem is: for some 'userid' there is exactly one corresponding 'etime', for which.loc() subsetting returns not a dataframe with one row indexed by 'userid' but a series object indexed by the array:

```
Index([u'etime', u'requested', u'rejected'], dtype='object')
```

And that's why changing index fails. Checking dimensions and index every time I select some dataframe subset looks pretty ugly. What else can I do about it?

UPD2: here is the script demonstrating the case

```
full_etime_range = range(10)
df = DataFrame(index=[0,0,1],
               columns=['etime','requested'],
               data=[[0,1],[1,1],[1,1]])

for i in df.index:
    tmp = df.loc[i]
    tmp.index = tmp['etime']
    tmp = tmp.reindex(full_etime_range,fill_value = 0)
    print tmp
```

Comment: I'm not really sure to understand what you want to do, can you provide a simple example reproducing your Error, along with the expected behavior.

Comment: produce a script for us that reproduces your dataframe.

Comment: Since you're new: No need for a script, if you don't have one at hand. `df.reset_index(inplace=true)` and paste the output of `print df.head()` should be enough to get your dataframe using `pd.read_clipboard()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, starting with `df` being your dataframe, we can do the following safely:

```
In[215]: df.set_index([df.index, 'etime'], inplace=True)
In[216]: df
Out[216]: 
         requested
  etime           
0 0              1
  1              1
1 1              1

DF = pd.DataFrame(index=full_etime_range, columns=[])
df0 = DF.copy()
In[225]: df0.join(df.loc[0])
Out[225]: 
   requested
0          1
1          1
2        NaN
3        NaN
4        NaN
5        NaN
6        NaN
7        NaN
8        NaN
9        NaN
In[230]: df1 = DF.copy()
In[231]: df1.join(df.loc[1])
Out[231]: 
   requested
0        NaN
1          1
2        NaN
3        NaN
4        NaN
5        NaN
6        NaN
7        NaN
8        NaN
9        NaN
```

which is technically what you want. But behold, we can do this nicer:

```
listOfDf = [DF.copy().join(df.loc[i]) for i in df.index.get_level_values(1).unique()]
```

I wanted to do it even one level nicer, but the following did not work - maybe someone can chip in why.

```
df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: DF.copy().join(x))
```

Comment: This works for me. Setting index to the 'userid-etime' pair does the trick. This way, .loc[] subsetting does return exactly what I expect. For some reason I didn't think it would make any difference. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to fill nas? Why are you reindexing the dataframe?

Just

```
user_entries = D.loc[userid]
user_entries.fillna(0)
```

Should do the trick. But if you are willing to fillna just for the etime field, what you should do is:

```
user_entries = D.loc[userid]
temp = user_entries["etime"].fillna(0)
user_extries["etime"] = temp
```

Hope it helps. If not, clarify what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Please refer to the UPD above.